# How do I save and re-export my SMD model and maintain the changes made?

Tags: modeling, armature, export, bones, import

***What I did:***

**Step 1:** imported SMD model (came with bone structure/armature)

[image]

**Step 2:** scaled the model to fit the bone structure and rotated it 180 degrees (z axis)

**Step 3:** properly fit the bone structure to the model, moving around the bones

**Step 4:** saved the imported SMD file as a blend file, 'untitled.blend', after the changes were made

**Step 5:** reopened the blend file to see if the changes were maintained with success

[image: this is what the model looked like after I made the changes and reopened the saved blender file]

**Step 6:** rescaled the model and bone structure both to .9

**Step 7:** exported the blend file to SMD and reopened the file

[image: the bone structure positioning default but changes to the scale of the model maintain]

***What I am trying to do:***

I am attempting to re-export the blender file back to SMD with the changes I made above. When I open the re-exported SMD file, after making changes and re-exporting, the SMD file saves no changes to the position of the bone structure, it defaults to its 'normal' position. When I re-export and reopen the new SMD file I expect the model and bone structure to look like image 2: all changes should be maintained.

Comment: Don't know anything about "SMD" but [this](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Animation_in_Blender) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Someone here can further elaborate as I am new, though, the issue was that I was editing the "pose position" of the bone structure and expecting the export to respect the changes. Only rest positioning is taken into account when exporting. So, set your new pose position to the rest position. The pose position was what you were managing or making changes to.
[image]